# using simplejavamail, how can i change message-ID?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, mime-types

https://github.com/bbottema/simple-java-mail

I'am using simple this library to send emails.
Can someone tell me how can i override message-ID before sending my email ?
Here is my code:

```
Mailer mailer = new Mailer(new ServerConfig(this.smtpHost, this.smtpPort, 
this.from, this.password),TransportStrategy.SMTP_TLS, new 
ProxyConfig(sockHost, sockPort));

mailer.trustAllSSLHosts(true);

mailer.sendMail(new EmailBuilder().from(this.user, this.from).to(to, 
to).subject(this.subject).textHTML(this.body).build());
```

I desperately try this after googling

```
 Session session = mailer.getSession();
 MimeMessage m = new testmm(session, "12345@test.test");
 m.saveChanges();
```

And here is testmm class code (copied from another topic here)

```
 public class testmm extends MimeMessage {
 private String messageID;

 public testmm(Session session, String messageID) {
 super(session);
 this.messageID = messageID;
 }

 @Override
 protected void updateMessageID() throws MessagingException {
 setHeader("Message-ID", messageID);
 }  
 }
```

Surely it doesn't work because i'am overriding another MimeMessage Object not the one used from this API.
Has somebody found this issue before ?
 any proposal is welcome.

Comment: I can't see any obvious way to do it, so I have to ask... why do you want to change the Message-ID?  Maybe there's a different way to solve your problem?  Or, you could just use the JavaMail APIs directly and avoid simple-java-mail.

Comment: I'am using simple-java-mail because i need to connect to a sock server before sending email and with javaMail API it's not simple .:/

Comment: JavaMail supports connecting through a SOCKS server, as long as the SOCKS server doesn't require authentication.  See the [`mail.smtp.socks.host` property](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html#mail.smtp.socks.host).

Comment: Yes sir, i not mention that i need authentication :/

Comment: @BillShannon, @DocMoo it actually super simple: `yourEmailBuilder.fixingMessageId("<123@456>");`. Is there anything about the documentation that you would like to see improved?

Answer (score 0):

The [Simple Java Mail documentation website](http://www.simplejavamail.org/) actually describes overriding with [custom Message-ID](http://www.simplejavamail.org/features.html#section-custom-id) explicitly and it couldn't be simpler!

```java
yourEmailBuilder.fixingMessageId("<123@456>");
```